# Random values from an asymmetric normal distribution from uniform distributed random values?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, transformation

I'm writing a programm in a programming language which has a function to generate uniform distributed random values.

I need to make "asymmetric normal distributed" values out of them. 
By that I mean that it should be more likely to get values lower than the median than higher ones. I know that this is probably not called a normal distribution anymore, but I wasn't able to come up with a better explanation.

I have two more annotations:

- I don't want to get the median itself, so it should have a probabilty of 0%. I could just execute the algorythm again if it wouldn't accomplish this, so the point isn't that important
- If it makes it easier I only need a binomial distribution, because I need integer values in the end. But my researches so far showed more results using a normal distribution and rounding afterwards.

I already found out how to do this with a typical normal distribution without the asynchronous aspect here on math.stackexchange: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/69245/12864

And I came up with the idea that maybe two compound normal distributions would do the trick:

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRL4z.png)

Comment: *asymmetric* or *skewed* might be better words than *asynchronous*.

Comment: A discrete distribution with a median of zero probability would be unusual

Comment: You are totally right, maybe I should've said peak instead of median.At least the point where the peak would be if it wouldn't be zero. In an asymmetric distribution it wouldn't be the median anymore.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I hope what I'm trying to say is still clear enough, cause I find it hard to describe. If not, I could try to phrase if differently. I know that the case is unusual, but it should be possible, shouldn't it?